# Corrupted page table at address

Tags: handle

I have a driver that mapping system RAM memory by using function remap_pfn_range. However recently I encounter a following problem when writing to the mapping memory region:

BUG: unable to handle kernel 
mydriver: Corrupted page table at address ffff88117ff72000

Could anyone explain for me what does exactly the "corrupted page table at address" means?

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for : http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Table

Answer (score 1):

The page table is the part of the OS that keeps track of pages of memory and where they are (disk, RAM, etc.)

Somewhere there is a pointer to this page table <0xffff88117ff72000>, and it is either messed up or the place it points to is messed up. Either way, the error message indicates the page table isn't understandable at this point.

Comment: As I know on 32 bit architecture, kernel uses two page level architecture: page directory and page table and offset. Page directory and page table have 1024 entries. 1024x1024x4096=4G, if page size is 4k. Every process has its own memory in page table. How a process memory can conflict with other processes in page table?

Comment: It shouldn't conflict. Probably something messed up the table in memory.

Comment: Could you tell me more clearly about the messed up the table as you said?

Comment: It's really hard to say what it might be without seeing actual dumps of the table at different times. Maybe the pointer to the table got overwritten. Maybe something was written wrong into the table so now it looks corrupted to the OS. Your probably want to start looking at how the page table changes over time, which is probably going to be somewhat painful. :/